# conversion pine script v2 to v3

Tags: pine-script, indicator

This is my code.

```
isBuyPlotted=isBuyPlotted[1]==true?true:nz(buySetup[MAXSIGNALDELAY+1])==9?true:false or nz(buySetup)==9?false:buySignal[1]==true  // init

buySignal=nz(buySetup[MAXSIGNALDELAY])>9-MAXSIGNALDELAY and close>nz(high[1]) and nz(close[1])>nz(open[1]) and nz(close)>nz(open) and not isBuyPlotted
```

I try to modify pine version 2 to version 3.

```
isBuyPlotted=0.0
isBuyPlotted:=isBuyPlotted[1]==true?true:nz(buySetup[MAXSIGNALDELAY+1])==9?true:false or nz(buySetup)==9?false:buySignal[1]==true  // init
buySignal=0.0
buySignal:=nz(buySetup[MAXSIGNALDELAY])>9-MAXSIGNALDELAY and close>nz(high[1]) and nz(close[1])>nz(open[1]) and nz(close)>nz(open) and not isBuyPlotted
```

But this error happens.
Variable `buySignal` was declared with float type. Cannot assign it expression of type series[bool]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both those variables are of type `bool` in the original code but you have declared them as `float`. That's what the error message tells you.

Change it to:

```
isBuyPlotted=false
buySignal=false
isBuyPlotted:=isBuyPlotted[1]==true?true:nz(buySetup[MAXSIGNALDELAY+1])==9?true:false or nz(buySetup)==9?false:buySignal[1]==true  // init
buySignal:=nz(buySetup[MAXSIGNALDELAY])>9-MAXSIGNALDELAY and close>nz(high[1]) and nz(close[1])>nz(open[1]) and nz(close)>nz(open) and not isBuyPlotted
```

Comment: I tried and this error happens.
 Undeclared identifier `buySignal`;

Comment: It looks like you need both declarations first. I have modified my code, please try again.